# NSURLConnection connecting to server, but not posting data

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, http-post, nsurlconnection

Whenever I attempt to post something to my PHP Server, I receive the following message. It seems as if the code is connecting to the server, but no data is returned, and the post data isn't going through. It worked through a Java App that I made, so I can assure that their is nothing wrong with my PHP. If you could help me, or need any more code to help me, just ask for it. Thanks.

Here is the code that prepares my variables for the NSURLConnection:

```
NSString *phash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",phashnum];
        [phash stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
name = _nameField.text;
        [name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        email = _emailField.text;
        [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Here is the code for my NSURLConnection:

```
NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://54.221.224.251"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPath];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *stringdata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&phash=%@",name,email,phash];
    NSOperationQueue *queue= [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
    NSString *postData = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:stringdata];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if ([data length] > 0 && connectionError==nil){
            NSLog(@"Connection Success. Data Returned");
            NSLog(@"Data = %@",data);
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
            NSString *coder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",code];
            NSLog(@"%@",coder);
        }
        else if([data length] == 0 && connectionError == nil){
            NSLog(@"Connection Success. No Data returned.");
            NSLog(@"Connection Success. Data Returned");
            NSLog(@"Data = %@",data);
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
            NSString *coder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",code];
            NSLog(@"%@",coder);
        }
        else if(connectionError != nil && connectionError.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut){
            NSLog(@"Connection Failed. Timed Out");
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
            NSString *coder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",code];
            NSLog(@"%@",coder);

        }
        else if(connectionError != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",connectionError);
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
            NSString *coder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",code];
            NSLog(@"%@",coder);

        }
    }];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use AFNetworking, it makes your life a lot easier! https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @elk said, you should replace spaces with `+`. But you should percent-encode reserved characters (as defined in [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)).

Unfortunately, the standard `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` does not percent escape all of the reserved characters. For example, if the name was "Bill & Melinda Gates" or "Bill + Melinda Gates", `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` would not percent escape the `&` or the `+` (and thus the `+` would have been interpreted as a space, and the `&` would have been interpreted as delimiting the next `POST` parameter).

Instead, use [`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001206-CH1g-F16659), supplying the necessary reserved characters in the `legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped` parameter and then replace the spaces with `+`. For example, you might define a `NSString` category:

```
@implementation NSString (PercentEscape)

- (NSString *)stringForPostParameterValue:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
{
    NSString *string = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@";/?:@&=+$,",
                                                                                 CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding)));
    return [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}

@end
```

Note, I was primarily concerned with the `&` and `+`, characters, but [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) (which supersedes RFC1738) listed those additional characters as being reserved, so it's probably prudent to include all of those reserved characters in the `legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped`.

Pulling this together, I might have code that posts the request as:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"name" : _nameField.text ?: @"",
                         @"email": _emailField.text ?: @"",
                         @"phash": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",phashnum]};

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURLString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[self httpBodyForParamsDictionary:params]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"sendAsynchronousRequest error = %@", error);

    if (data) {
        // do whatever you want with the data
    }
}];
```

Using a utility method:

```
- (NSData *)httpBodyForParamsDictionary:(NSDictionary *)paramDictionary
{
    NSMutableArray *paramArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [paramDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [obj stringForPostParameterValue:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [paramArray addObject:param];
    }];

    NSString *string = [paramArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];

    return [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"name=%@&email=%@&phash=%@" is not a proper url-encoded string. Each key-value pair has to be separated by an '&' character, and each key from its value by an '=' character. Keys and values are both escaped by replacing spaces with the '+' character and then encoded by `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`.

See [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application/x-www-form-urlencoded#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type).

You can find a recipe how to do this in [this blog post](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/08/url-encoding/).

Comment: I updated the code above, and it works, the server accepts it.

Comment: Can you check above to make sure that the code is correct now? Because their is another, separate, issue I'm having.

Comment: You have to replace spaces by '+' first - I guess `name` ist the only string that can contain spaces.

Comment: I can't just percent encode the space? and it sets it to %20?

Comment: No, %20 is **not** fine, [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) states that "space characters are replaced by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in ([RFC1738])[http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/references.html#ref-RFC1738], section 2.2".
It may be that your server doesn't care and %20 works, but it's the wrong encoding.

Comment: @elk Agreed, you should not use `%20` (even though it works). But then, again, you shouldn't use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, either. You really should use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`.